# REST AJAX request to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, jquery

I am trying to fire a `XMLHttpRequest` to mongoDB to retrieve a document via AJAX.

This is my code:

```
function getJsonDocumentByModeldid(model_id) {
    var valoreInput = document.getElementById('inputModelId').value;
    alert(valoreInput);

    $.ajax({
      url: "http://localhost:28017/test/",
      type: "get",
      //data: "filter_a=" + valoreInput,
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      crossDomain: true,

      success: function (data) {
        alert("success");
        //var json2javascript = $.parseJSON(data);
        manageLayout();
      },

      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
       alert("Status: " + textStatus + "    Error:" + errorThrown);
      }
  });
}
```

My function always returns an error. So what is the problem?

Comment: the ajax request fails with the script, instead if i copy url in browser, the server response with success.
i don't know what is the problem...

Comment: The alert error is Jqueryxxxxxx was not called!

Comment: yes.. i start the server with the command mongod --rest. i  try with datatype json,but the problem persist

Comment: Is the page that your JavaScript is running on loaded from a web server (running locally) or just a simple HTML page loaded in a browser? It might be the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem.

Comment: is a simple page loaded in a browser..this is my step: 
1)launch the server in windows terminal with the command "mongod.exe --rest" 
2)if i click http://127.0.0.1:28017/ilariodb/ilariodb/?filter_name=mongo, i have the response.
if instead i launch my script the ajax request go in error!

how i can load my web page which include a script for the response in  mongodb's web server?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This functionality is supported as part of the [Simple (read-only) REST Interface](http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tools/http-interfaces/) but to make cross domain requests the [`--jsonp`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/mongod/#cmdoption-mongod--jsonp) otherwise you will be subject to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) problem, since the IP address and port that you are making the request from do not match the IP address and port that mongoDB is running on.

Start **mongoDB** with `mongod.exe --rest --jsonp` (plus any other options you may have).

The following example page can be served via a web sever (for example [Apache HTTP Server](http://httpd.apache.org/)) or simply saved locally and loaded in the browser as a *file*. The request is for information about a dbCollection called *andyb*, which I created in mongoDB first with:

```
db.createCollection('andyb');
```

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <title>mongoDB AJAX demo</title>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:28017/local/andyb',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp', // mongod is expecting the parameter name to be called "jsonp"
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('success', data);
      },
      error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log('error', errorThrown);
      }
    });
  });//]]>
  </script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Many browsers support [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) now which is an alternative (more modern) way to facilitate cross domain resources.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer can be modified by using deferred objects (see this good guide:
"[How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)):

```
<!doctype html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>mongoDB AJAX demo</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" ></script>
<script>    
    $(function(){ 
    // add rest = true and jsonp = true to /etc/mongodb.conf, 
    // then restart mongodb
         $.ajax({
                url: "http://localhost:28017/local/startup_log/",
                type: 'get',
                dataType: 'jsonp',
                jsonp: 'jsonp', // mongodb is expecting that                                                                                     
            })
            .done(function(data) {
                d=JSON.stringify(data,undefined,1);
                $("code").text(d).css("color","green");
            })
            .fail(function(request,status,error) {
                $("code").text("get failed: "+error).css("color","red");
            })
            .always(function() {
                console.log("finished")
            })

  });
</script>
<body>
  <pre>
    <code>
    </code>
  </pre>
```

Anyway,  in both situations the `error:` and `fail()` handling works only if a port is not provided. For instance:

```
url:"localhost/asdasdasd"
```

results in an error handling; while

```
url:"localhost:28017/asdasdasd"
```

results in a 404 log in the console, like this:

```
GET http://localhost:28017/?jsonp=jQuery110207253803350031376_1383522587177&_=1383522587178 404 (OK)
```