# Can we send data from mongoDB to HTML?

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb, express

I am working on a Mini Project where I have stored data coming from a form in my DataBase(MongoDB). Now I want to fetch data from MongoDB and want to add it to HTML(as a list) to display on the webpage.
I wanted to do this without using ejs or any other tool. Is this possible? If yes,then how?
(I have used Expressjs to create the server)

Comment: You can use the ***res.send(`\`${message}\``)*** assuming message to be the data you want to send

Answer (score 0):

You would have to javascript in order to manipulate DOM elements on the page.
(see. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Client-side_web_APIs/Manipulating_documents)

Comment: document is not accessible in the js file where I have written server side code.

Comment: Right, you would have to pull in your data thru a front-end request (something like AJAX would work) then manipulate that data on the front-end.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch the data in your html then add it to your page by manipulating the dom.
This is might help you:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function(){
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost:28017/local/students',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp',
      jsonp: 'jsonp',
      success: function (data) {
        console.log('success', data);
      }
    }).done(function(){
        let output = '<div>'
        $.each(data, function(key, data){
            output += '<p>' +  data.score + '</p>';
        });
        output += '</div>'
        $('#list').html(output);
    });
  });
  </script>
```

Also this response might be helpful:
[REST AJAX request to mongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16164604/rest-ajax-request-to-mongodb)

Answer (score 0):

Since you have mentioned you are using Expressjs, I believe you are also using an ODM like mongoose. Hence, you should create an api in your backend that fetches the data from MongoDB (see your ODM's documentation for it) and send request to that api from your front end, whose response should trigger DOM manipulation.

Here are some resources that might help you:

- https://medium.com/swlh/how-to-build-simple-restful-api-with-nodejs-expressjs-and-mongodb-e59595091640
- https://medium.com/@ingridf/flow-of-fetch-and-dom-manipulation-454af047b6c
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn